# After a recent update to Ubuntu 22.04, I can no longer use my bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth

After a recent update to Ubuntu 22.04, I can no longer use my bluetooth headset.  The headset connects, but is not recognized as a device in sound settings.  It is also not recognized in the pulseaudio volume control. I have pulse audio, pipewire and alsa installed.  I have searched the internet for similar problems, but none of the answers have solved my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you have 20.04 Focal Fossa before?

Comment: Yes, but I upgraded to 22.04 when it first came out.  At that point, Bluetooth was working. This is a problem that has occurred within the last week.

Comment: Look at Bluetooth section of the 'sudo inxi -Fxmz' command. What is the kernel driver installed?

Comment: Here is everything that came up from sudo ini -Fxmz.  sudo inxi -Fxmz
[sudo] password for paul: 
System:
  Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ENVY dv7 Notebook PC
    v: 0884110014305910000620120 serial: <filter>
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 181C v: 52.24 serial: <filter> UEFI: Insyde
    v: F.2E date: 09/07/2016

Comment: There is Bluetooth section in the inxi output when I run it on my computer. In the Settings->Bluetooth there is a list of devices.

Comment: In the bluetooth settings my paired device does show up, but when I connect to it, pulse audio does not detect it.  When I go to the sound settings, the device is not there, and if I open the pulse audio volume control, it is also not listed.  Sound will come through the speakers, but not through the headset.

Comment: Upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS -> 22.04 LTS and have same problem. The headset is found, but unrecognized as audio device. Headset is working with all other devices (other laptops, iphone, etc). Following many tips but still can't get it working :(